# How to align Tikz picture in fancyhdr header to the document edges?

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr

I am preparing a template and I should add a bookmark-like icon in the edges with the page number. This works fine with tikz, however, the edges of the icon are not aligned with the document edge. If just putting the plain page number in the header then this is aligned at the edge. Can anyone give me a hint on how to solve this? Cheers!

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
    inner=2.5cm, outer=2.0cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,
    includehead=false, % Kopfzeile außerhalb des Textkörper, also im Rand
    includefoot=false,
    headheight = \baselineskip,
    headsep = 25mm,
    showframe}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\newcommand{\bmshapel}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=black]
    (0.4,0) node {}
    -- (1,0) node {}
    -- (1,2) node {}
    -- (0,2) node {}
    -- (0,0.4) node {};
    \node[text=white, align=center] at (0.5, 0.7){\textsl{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\bmshaper}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=black]
    (0.6,0) node {}
    -- (1,0.4) node {}
    -- (1,2) node {}
    -- (0,2) node {}
    -- (0,0) node {};
    \node[text=white, align=center] at (0.5, 0.7){\textsl{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\fancypagestyle{reg}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[OL]{\bmshapel{\thepage}}%
    \fancyhead[OR]{\bmshaper{\thepage}}}%

\pagestyle{reg}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\lipsum[1-3]


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the empty nodes, and add a `%` after `\end{tikzpicture}`

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,
    inner=2.5cm, outer=2.0cm,top=3cm,bottom=2.5cm,
    includehead=false, % Kopfzeile außerhalb des Textkörper, also im Rand
    includefoot=false,
    headheight = \baselineskip,
    headsep = 25mm,
    showframe}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{2pt}

\newcommand{\bmshapel}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=black]
    (0.4,0)
    -- (1,0)
    -- (1,2)
    -- (0,2)
    -- (0,0.4);
    \node[text=white, align=center] at (0.5, 0.7){\textsl{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand{\bmshaper}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=black]
    (0.6,0)
    -- (1,0.4)
    -- (1,2)
    -- (0,2)
    -- (0,0);
    \node[text=white, align=center] at (0.5, 0.7){\textsl{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\fancypagestyle{reg}{%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyhead[OL]{\bmshapel{\thepage}}%
    \fancyhead[OR]{\bmshaper{\thepage}}}%

\pagestyle{reg}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\lipsum[1-3]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) You made my day!